# Getting A MongoId out of an array

Tags: php

How would I call the id by itself?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [_id] => MongoId Object
                (
                    [$id] => 4f98930cb1445d0a7d000001
                )
        )

)
```

I thought it would be:

```
echo $userInfo[0]['_id']->['$id'];
```

Comment: hmm maybe like this `echo $userInfo[0]['_id']->id;` and use var_dump() for debug

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As _id is a [MongoId](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongoid.php) object, you should access it's public members like this:

```
echo $userInfo[0]['_id']->id;
```

EDIT: 
The MongoId $id field [starts with a dollar sign](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongoid.php#104850) so you may have to call it by {'$id'}, else PHP won't parse it correctly. (thanks @cKendrick)

```
echo $userInfo[0]['_id']->{'$id'};
```

Comment: that gave me a `ErrorException [ Notice ]: Undefined property: MongoId::$id`

Comment: nm I figured it out, its actually `echo $userInfo[0]['_id']->{'$id'};`